error in \underbrace command
I have some code ready in Overleaf for a dissertation in which I am using the \underbrace command and everything is working fine there, it comes out the way I need it.
But due to Overleaf limitations I am transferring it to TexMaker. The problem is that the same command presents a strange error in TexMaker.
\begin{displaymath}
    \phi(x_{i_1}x_{i_2} \dotsm x_{i_n})
    = \phi(x_{i_1})\phi(x_{i_2}) \dotsm \phi(x_{i_n})
    = \underbrace{1 + 1 + \dotsm + 1}_{n \text{ vezes}}
    = n.
\end{displaymath}

the expected result,Overleaf

the result in TexMaker

my system is Windows 11
I'm using MikTek

Try \LaTeXunderbrace instead of \underbrace

I am unable to reproduce your screenshot -- indeed, I'm unable to create any kind of situation -- if I make your code snippet minimally compilable by prefixing it with \documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} and affixing \end{document} to it. Please provide more information about your computing setup. E.g., which version of MikTeX do you use? When was it last updated? Do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document?

Off-topic: The third instance of \dotsm in the code snippet should be either \dotsb or, more simply, \dots.
